# Getfield.SetValue doesn't work

Tags: c#, reflection, pinvoke

in my project i'm currently working on i stumbled upon this problem:

I want to create a Instance of the Class "ApiID". I got the Code from Reflector, as you can see the .dll (not my Project) imports is from ummanaged code, which i don't have access to.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=0x10), CLSCompliant(false), NativeCppClass, DebugInfoInPDB, MiscellaneousBits(0x40)]
public struct ApiId
{
    private long <alignment member>;
    public static unsafe void <MarshalCopy>(ApiId* idPtr1, ApiId* idPtr2)
    {
        ApiId.{ctor}(idPtr1, (ApiId modopt(IsConst)* modopt(IsImplicitlyDereferenced)) idPtr2);
    }

    public static unsafe void <MarshalDestroy>(ApiId* idPtr1)
    {
        ApiId.{dtor}(idPtr1);
    }
}
```

My C#-Code looks like this:

```
var _apiId = new ApiId();
long vlue = 0x0000000041403070;
typeof(ApiId).GetField("<alignment member>", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(_apiId, vlue);
```

The Code Runs succesfully, but the Field  does not change and stays 0... what am I doing wrong?
greetings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is *boxing*.

This line:

```
typeof(ApiId).GetField("<alignment member>", ...).SetValue(_apiId, vlue);
```

will box the struct value in `_apiId` and set the field value of the boxed copy. It will not change the original.

[FieldInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined like this:

```
public void SetValue(
    Object obj,
    Object value
)
```

So the first parameter, your `_apiId` will be boxed. Boxing will make a copy of the struct value. SetValue will thus change the boxed copy and not the original.

Instead, you can box the object yourself:

```
object apiId = new ApiId();
long vlue = ...
typeof(ApiId)...
_apiId = (ApiId)apiId;
```

Here's a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/waKaJ6) that demonstrates. Try changing which line is commented out to see the difference.

Comment: Tried the Fiddle, works in C#, not when translated to VB though.