# Giving a Pointer to GetField.SetValue in Reflection

Tags: c#, pointers, object, reflection

after solving this problem, there is one error left in my task ([previous question about ApiID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226731/getfield-setvalue-doesnt-work)). With Reflection i want to set a field, which is a pointer:

```
 public class TxObjectImpl : IDisposable
    {
     protected unsafe ApiId* _id;
    }
```

I tried to implement it like this:

```
object _apiId = new ApiId(); 
ApiId apiID = (ApiId)_apiId;
ApiId* pointer = &apiID;
typeof(TxObjectImpl).GetField("_id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(_TxObjectImpl, pointer);
```

Visual studio gives me this error:

> Argument type 'ApiId*' is not assignable to parameter type 'object'

Is this even possible with Reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast your pointer to `IntPtr` first.

```
.SetValue(_TxObjectImpl, (IntPtr) pointer)
```