# Parameter values are not mapped in Web API, if the Model class is marked as Serializable

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api Controller as shown below

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    ....
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Add")]
    public IHttpActionResult Add(Employee emp)
    {
        ...
    }
}

 [Serializable]
 public class Employee
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

The parameters send in the Http Post request gets mapped in the Controller only when the `[Serializable]` attribute is removed from the Employee class. If I add the attribute, the value for the property `Name` in the `Employee` class is always `null`

Can someone explain whats going wrong, when the model class is marked as `[Serializable]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why this is happening, you need to understand the precise meaning of [`SerializableAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx).  It means **This class can be serialized by serializing its public and private *fields*** (i.e., not its properties).  The attribute dates from c# 1.0, back when all properties had explicit backing fields, and was used initially by `BinaryFormatter`.  So, when auto-implemented properties were introduced in c# 3.0, how were they to be serialized?

Not all serializers support `[Serializable]`, but those that do serialize auto-implemented properties by serializing their [hidden backing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817070/is-it-possible-to-access-backing-fields-behind-auto-implemented-properties) by name and value.   You don't say what version of Web API you are using, nor the data format (XML or JSON), so you might be using:

- `DataContractSerializer`.  The data contract serializers support `[Serializable]`, as stated in [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The XML data contract serializer serializes your `Employee` class as follows:

  ```
  <Employee>
      <_x003C_Name_x003E_k__BackingField>My Name</_x003C_Name_x003E_k__BackingField>
  </Employee>
  ```
- `DataContractJsonSerializer` also serializes the backing fields, producing:

  ```
  {"<Name>k__BackingField":"My Name"}
  ```
- Json.NET will serialize the backing fields only if [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm):

  ```
      var employee = new Employee { Name = "My Name" };
      var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false } });
      Console.WriteLine(json1);
  ```

  Also produces `{"<Name>k__BackingField":"My Name"}`.  Without the setting, Json.NET ignores the attribute.
- `XmlSerializer` ignores `[Serializable]`.
- `JavaScriptSerializer` also ignores `[Serializable]`.

The [current version](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter) of Web API uses Json.NET and `XmlSerializer`, but this is configurable.  Earlier versions [use the data contract serializers](http://techblog.dorogin.com/2012/05/json-serializers-in-aspnet-and-other.html) or sometimes even `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Thus, the reason that your `Name` property is null is that you are using one of the serializers that support `[Serializable]` and you are posting JSON or XML that does not have the goofy backing field property name.

To work around this problem, you have the following options:

1. Annotate your class with [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  These supersede `[Serializable]` for all serializers that support it:

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [DataContract]
   public class Employee
   {
       [DataMember]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. If you are using XML, be sure you are using `XmlSerializer` as specified in [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter).
3. If you are using JSON and Json.NET in MVC 4 Web API, you can set `IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true` in Global.asax.cs in [`Application_Start`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274625/how-to-set-custom-jsonserializersettings-for-json-net-in-mvc-4-web-api):

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
       config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
           new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true };
   }
   ```
4. Or, just remove `[Serializable]`, you really don't need it for anything other than `BinaryFormatter`.