# Added [Serializable()] to my DTO and now getting an error with deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.7.2

Working on moving one of our projects from inproc to using SOSS and ran into some errors that indicated some of our models/dtos needed to be serializable. For all but one of these, adding

```
[Serializable()]
```

to the top of the class resolved all issues. For the remaining one, it is now returning this error:

> System.Exception: An service exception has occured the exception was System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetAllAttachmentsResult. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 686. 'EndElement' 'YourDTO' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Business.Objects.Message' is not expected. Expecting element '_x003C_AttachmentDate_x003E_k__BackingField'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 686. 'EndElement' 'YourDTO' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Business.Objects.Message' is not expected. Expecting element '_x003C_AttachmentDate_x003E_k__BackingField'.

Here is the DTO:

```
    namespace Business.Objects.Message
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class YourDTO
    {
       public long Id { get; set; }
       public FileType Type{ get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime AttachmentDate { get; set; }
       public string UserName { get; set; }

   
   public YourDTO()
   {
       Id = 0;
       Name = string.Empty;
       Type = FileType.Unknown;
       AttachmentDate = DateTime.MinValue;
       UserName = string.Empty;

   }
}
}
```

The code that uses this simply populates the DTO from a db as a DataTable and then sends back the list of DTOs after mapping.

Couple things to note:

1. This DTO is passed through a nuget package to the solution in question.
2. I did try [DataContract] as well but this did not work either.
3. This has worked for years up to this point. Only change is adding SOSS to web.config for SessionState and the [Serializable() attribute addition.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might not be this class, but the class that contains and instance of the object

Comment: Have you got some sort of rule or serializer option that treats default values as null? Try with a date that is not `MinValue`

Comment: Oh right, _Deserialize_ ... Please show the serialized value, sounds like the property is missing.

Comment: Adding `[Serializable]` to your DTO will cause the data contract serializer to serialize its public and private **fields** (including the `... k__BackingField` secret backing fields of auto properties) instead of the properties.  The solution is to remove `[Serializable]` or mark the type with data contract attributes.  See e.g. [Is there a way to make DataContractSerializer output cleaner XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31498951/3744182) or [Parameter values are not mapped in Web API, if the Model class is marked as Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33215188/3744182).

Comment: You wrote *I did try [DataContract] as well but this did not work either.* -- then please share what you tried.  If you need to mark your types with `[Serializable]` then you will need to decorate them with data contract attributes to counteract that.

Comment: @dbc thank you so much! That was the piece I was missing and this fixed my issue.

Comment: @EveryDayDev - you're welcome, glad to help.  Do my comments + the linked questions fully answer your question, or do you still need some help?

Comment: @dbc that fully answers it! Mind to post an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Rather than add an answer, I went ahead and marked it a a dup of [Parameter values are not mapped in Web API, if the Model class is marked as Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33215188/3744182).