# C# - How do properties access a private field using getter/setter short hand

Tags: c#

I am perplexed as in my spare time I've been reading through C# books to become familiar with the language.

I stumbled upon the use of properties; in this context it is in regards to using a getter/setter for a privately declared field in my class.

This is what I have in my code as to keep it simple:

```
class ClassName
{
   private int hWorked = 24;
   public int HoursWorked
     {
       get
        {
          return hWorked;
        }
     }
}
```

Now the book says that:

> If I use the short hand version - `public int HoursWorked {get;}` -
>   that it is the same as the above code.

But what I *need clarification* on is how the shorthand *is able to return* the `hWorked` value without specifying that the `hWorked = value`.

In simple terms: How does the `HoursWorked` getter know to target my privately declared `hWorked`.

Comment: `public int HoursWorked {get;} ` creates its own backing field and *doesn't address* `hWorked`

Comment: I think the book means that if you replace *both* the variable and the property with just an auto-implemented property the (observable) result is the same

Comment: Now with regards to that, if I were to use the shorthand to create an anonymous backing field would I remove the private variable hWorked as it is not needed in this particular instance. Also is there a way to find the name of this backing field?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: @GaryStewart The backing field isn't necessarily named anything obvious or helpful. It can be accessed via reflection as an exercise, but as a rule, if you need a backing variable within scope, you need to create it yourself in order to maintain control of it.

Comment: What you call *shorthand* is *auto-implemented property*. And such property has 
backfield, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817070/1997232).

Comment: What Alex said, but you can in fact restrict setter access: `public int HoursWorked{ get; private set;}` and use `HoursWorked = 24` inside the class.

Answer (score 3):

Well `public int HoursWorked {get;}` creates *its own* backing field and *doesn't address* `hWorked`. The equivalent of the code in the question (shorthand version) is

```
  class ClassName {
    public int HoursWorked { get; } = 24;
  }
```

You can see the backing field with a help of *Reflection*:

```
  using System.Reflection;

  ... 

  var fields = string.Join(", ", typeof(ClassName)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(f => f.Name));

  Console.Write(fields);
```

Outcome (may vary):

```
  <HoursWorked>k__BackingField
```

If you inspect the *initial* `ClassName` implementation you'll get

```
  hWorked
```

Answer (score 1):

the shorthand version uses a "hidden" variable to store the values in.

if you write `public int hWorked {get; set;}` it reads and writes from a unnamed variable in the background.

Comment: [This shall help you in properly formatting your answers/questions :)](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)