# Auto-Implemented Property - signature of hidden member

Tags: c#

When creating an auto-implemented property, C# generates a member for that property somewhere in the background. I for the life of me can't remember what this is called, or what the naming convention for the member is called. After Googling for a while, I thought it might be an idea to just ask.

Property:

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

My guess (from memory) of the hidden member:

```
private int i_age;
```

**Edit #1**

To clarify, I was looking for the term of the auto generated member, which was answered by [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516599/auto-implemented-property-signature-of-hidden-member/51516696#51516696) below. The term is "backing field"

Comment: Why do you need this name? The name might change between C# versions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817070/is-it-possible-to-access-backing-fields-behind-auto-implemented-properties to get the name of the private backing-field.

Comment: It's an implementation detail and you should never ever write any code relying on that. This said...no, it generates an unique name which you can't create in your code then it will, for sure, includes _special characters_ which can't be used as C# identifiers.

Comment: Why do you care? you don't have access to that field anyway (except through reflection), and it is an implementation detail, as Adriano wrote in his comment...

Comment: I guess I phrased the question wrong, but what I wanted was the term used. So as Dmitry answered below, it's "backing field".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not carry out a simple *experiment*?

```
using System.Reflection;

...

public class Experiment {
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

...

var fieldNames = string.Join(", ", typeof(Experiment)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(field => field.Name));

Console.Write(fieldNames);
```

Outcome:

```
<Age>k__BackingField
```

Please, notice that unlike `i_age` actual field's name `<Age>k__BackingField` *doesn't conflict* with any field (we can't declare a field with such a name)

Comment: I'm not _too_ experienced with reflection, so I didn't know this was an option. This answer is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You may want to try this.

```
private int i_age;
public int Age 
{ 
    get {return i_age;} 
    set {i_age = value;}
}
```