# When should an explicit field be used over auto-properties?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Now that C# includes automatic properties and `private set`, you can emulate basic traditional accessors and modifiers without an explicit field, controlling access. You can even initialize properties now.

So excuse the stupid question but when *would/should* fields be preferred? Both technically - what limitations are there - and in terms of best practices and coding standards, how should a modern C# developer approach this?

One presumes MS added these features specifically *to* remove the need for declaring the field as well as the properties, so for simple cases is it *expected* that's what we do, and fields should be reserved for non-trivial cases?

Is my suggestion correct: **auto-properties should be used unless there is a reason not to?**

*I found this question: [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property) But C# has moved a long way since 2007, so I tagged this question C# v7 in case language features mean the answer has changed.*

Comment: Auto-properties are just syntactic sugar. They add no functionality. If you don't need to access the backing field directly then there's no advantage to declaring one.

Comment: @DStanley Question: if you use an auto-property is there still a field you can access directly then?

Comment: @Mr.Boy, [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817070/1997232).

Comment: @Mr.Boy Not directly. You can get to it through reflection but you don't know the compiler-generated name. If you need to access the backing field then you should declare one.

Comment: @Sinatr I would argue that reflection is not accessing "directly".

Comment: @DStanley, sorry, I miss that word..