# locking Property without a private variable

Tags: c#, multithreading

[image]

Basically I want to achieve using a lock to a property that has no private variable, the goal is to have thread safe Properties instead of doing it manually each time.

But not sure how to write that, so the lines aren't red! :)

```
    public class TestingLOL
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } // Working non private property but is not thread safe.

        public int IdWithLock { get => lock (this); set; } // this is what im trying to achieve without a private property.

        private int shitMethod;
        public int ShitMethod // fuck this way
        {
            get
            {
                ;
                lock (this)
                    return shitMethod;
            }
            set
            {
                ;
                lock (this)
                    shitMethod = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code

Comment: Necessary to show error highlighting. But posted code too now.

Comment: You should provide your code as text, rather than images

Comment: Locking an `int` getter is not useful at all as reading an `int` is an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you have to use the name of that backing field

```
 public int IdWithLock { get => { lock (this){return XXXX;}}; set; }
```

but that name is not available to you (see nice long discussion here
[Is it possible to access backing fields behind auto-implemented properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817070/is-it-possible-to-access-backing-fields-behind-auto-implemented-properties))

You just gonna have to do it the shty way