# .Net Xml Serializer uses private attribute name instead of public one

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xmlserializer

I've generate a class with xsd.exe and it came out like this (a partial):

```
public partial class MyClass{       

    private SignatureType signatureField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    public SignatureType Signature {
        get {
            return this.signatureField;
        }
        set {
            this.signatureField = value;
        }
    }    
}
```

I'm coding an Asp.Net 5 controller that outputs that object as an XML, the problem is that the seriarizer is using the private property's name instead of the public one ending up like this

```
<MyClass>
    <signatureField></signatureField>
</MyClass>
```

with the Field suffix.

What could be causing this?

thanks

Comment: Can you please show code that either returns object or performs serialization?

Comment: This could conceivably happen if 1) You marked your class as `[Serializable]` and 2) You are actually using `DataContractSerializer` not `XmlSerializer`.  You can check [Is there a way to make DataContractSerializer output cleaner XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953984/is-there-a-way-to-make-datacontractserializer-output-cleaner-xml) for details.  Likely you will need to provide a [complete examlple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help more.

Comment: Yes the class is marked as serializable, i will try without it.

Comment: The code that does the serialisation is .net mvc... The contoller returns an object and I'm asking for xml in the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the [Serializable] attribute did it for me.

thanks