# Why does [Serializable] cause Newtonsoft.Json serializer to include backing fields?

Tags: json.net, serializable

If I have [Serializable] attribute on a class then it causes the resulting serialised Json string to include backing members created by the framework.

For example I get below for my Id field:

```
<Id>k__BackingField=20001
```

I could find many resources on SOF and elsewhere to get around this problem but I couldn't find why Json serializer is behaving differently when it sees [Serializable] attribute.

If the Jason serializer doesn't serialise members and only serialise properties then why does it behave differently when a class is decorated with [Serializable] attribute?

**Please note I'm not looking for a way to fix this issue as I have already found that. I would like to know why Newtonsoft.Jsonserialiser behaves differently here.**

Comment: From [Serialization Guide: Objects](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Objects): *Finally, types can be serialized using a fields mode. All fields, both public and private, are serialized and properties are ignored. This can be specified by setting MemberSerialization.Fields on a type with the JsonObjectAttribute or by using the .NET SerializableAttribute and setting IgnoreSerializableAttribute on DefaultContractResolver to false.*

Comment: So your code must be setting [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm) somewhere; it's not the default.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Or wait: `<Id>k__BackingField=20001` looks like XML not JSON.  Are you sure you are using [tag:json.net] at all?  Can you share a [mcve]?  If you are actually using `DataContractSerializer` you can get these backing fields, see [Is there a way to make DataContractSerializer output cleaner XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1953984/3744182) for why.

Comment: @dbc the solution I'm working on uses WCF and Web API and like you said setting the IgnoreSerializableAttribute setting had fixed the problem. I asked this question as I couldn't find why Json.net was behaving this way. Thanks to the link you provided (Serialization guide:objects)  I understand this now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone wants to find the reason in the future, following explains how objects are serialised by Json.Net:

[Breakdown of Type Serialization > Objects](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Objects)

> By default a type's properties are serialized in opt-out mode. What
>   that means is that all public fields and properties with getters are
>   automatically serialized to JSON, and fields and properties that
>   shouldn't be serialized are opted-out by placing JsonIgnoreAttribute
>   on them. To serialize private members, the JsonPropertyAttribute can
>   be placed on private fields and properties.
>
> Types can also be serialized using opt-in mode. Only properties and
>   fields that have a JsonPropertyAttribute or DataMemberAttribute on
>   them will be serialized. Opt-in mode for an object is specified by
>   placing the JsonObjectAttribute or DataContractAttribute on the type.
>
> Finally, types can be serialized using a fields mode. All fields, both
>   public and private, are serialized and properties are ignored. This
>   can be specified by setting MemberSerialization.Fields on a type with
>   the JsonObjectAttribute or by using the .NET SerializableAttribute and
>   setting IgnoreSerializableAttribute on DefaultContractResolver to
>   false.